# Directive is rendering HTML before a variable is given a value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

I am running Django 1.9 and AngularJS 1.5.

My Django View looks like this:

```
#hello_world_view.py
def hello_world(request):
    t = get_template('hello-world.html')
    return HttpResponse(t.render())
```

The HTML file looks like this:

```
<-- loading JavaScript files above -->
<helloWorld><HelloWorld>
```

The AngularJS controller has a promise that is retrieving data from the Django REST API. It looks something like this

```
helloWorld.controller('helloWorldController', 
    function($scope, $helloWorldService1, $helloWorldService2) {
        Promise.all([$hWService1, $hWService2]).then(function(response) {
             $scope.service1 = response[0];
             $scope.service2 = response[1];
        });
    });
```

the directive looks like this:

```
// helloWorld is already defined as an app.
helloWorld.directive('helloWorldDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        link: function($scope, $elements, $attributes) {
            $scope.$watch('someVariable', function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    $elements.text(data);
                }
            }, true);
        },
        templateUrl: '/static/partials/some-template.html'
    }
});
```

Some template has variables inside it that are dependent on the promise from the controller being resolved. However, when I test it via.

```
>>> python manage.py runserver
```

the variables are not rendered. I already changed the tags from {{}} to [[]] for angularJS so I know that it's not Django accidentally trying to render these variables.

Is what I'm doing even possible? If so, is there a fix? Thanks.

EDIT: fixed grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to register the controller for the directive. Try adding:

controller: 'helloWorldController' to the return object of the directive.

Comment: Done, but it doesn't look like it helped... Thanks though!